# XML parsing in VBA

Tags: vba, xml-parsing

I am having troubles parsing XML returned from an API.  My main point on this is to get the "used" and "limit" properties of one of the nodes (with xPath).

For now I don't even manage to explore the whole XML tree, so here I come asking for help

The returned XML looks like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<QueryResultRecords xmlns="http://www.xmlns.loc/sub" type="application/some.app.query+xml" href="https://my.api.call.com/query?has_cheezburger" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.xmlns.loc/sub http://my.api.address.com/schema/master.xsd">
    <OnlyNodeType Name="name1" link="hhttp://my.api.address.com/a5d11b73dffe" Used="240640"  Limit="0"  />
    <OnlyNodeType Name="name2" link="http://my.api.address.com/03b11042ccd4"  Used="10240"  Limit="409600" />
    <OnlyNodeType Name="name3" link="http://my.api.address.com/1cf43be18e2e"  Used="11934947"  Limit="20971520" />
</QueryResultRecords>
```

I roughly understand how XMLDom works in VBA, but searching the web, I managed to write this, which obviously doesn't work...

```
Dim XMLDOC As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Dim nodelist As IXMLDOMNodeList
Set XMLDOC = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
XMLDOC.async = False
XMLDOC.validateOnParse = False
XMLDOC.Load (myhttpresponse)

Namespace = "xmlns: 'http://www.xmlns.loc/sub' "
Call XMLDOC.setProperty("SelectionNamespaces", Namespace)
Call XMLDOC.setProperty("SelectionLanguage", "XPath")

XPath = "/"

Set nodelist = XMLDOC.SelectNodes(XPath)
For i = 0 To nodelist.Length - 1
    Set Node = nodelist.NextNode
    Debug.Print Node.Text
Next i
```

I think it is an xml-treeing problem (I didn't understand something on XMLDom?) or an xmlns/xsi problem, and there I stuck completely.

Could Anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *must* choose a namespace prefix for every namespace you want to use, even if there is no prefix in the XML.

Here I use `sub` to refer to the `http://www.xmlns.loc/sub` namespace.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim XmlDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim OnlyNodeType As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement

    Set XmlDoc = GetXml("https://my.api.call.com/query?has_cheezburger")
    XmlDoc.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:sub='http://www.xmlns.loc/sub'"

    For Each OnlyNodeType In XmlDoc.SelectNodes("//sub:OnlyNodeType")
        Debug.Print OnlyNodeType.GetAttribute("link")
    Next OnlyNodeType
End Sub

Function GetXml(url As String) As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    With New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
        .Open url
        .Send
        Set GetXml = .responseXML
        GetXml.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
    End With
End Function
```

XML has the convenience facility of default namespaces (namespace declarations without an explicit prefix, like `xmlns="http://foo"` as opposed to `xmlns:foo="http://foo"`). This convenience facility does not exist for XPath. Here every namespace reference must be explicit.

As long as the namespace URI matches, you can choose any prefix you like.

Comment: I think you helped me a lot, thank you :) Small problem, though:
 Dim OnlyNodeType As MSXML2.DOMElement seems to be unrecognized by VBA. I loaded MS XML v6.0 but no reference of that anyway. I bet on a mistake from yours, but still?

Comment: Of course, I meant `IXMLDOMElement`. You could also use `IXMLDOMNode`. The node is the base type of the DOM element - it offers fewer methods and properties, but in exchange it works for all possible types of XPath query results. Use the Object Browser (F2 the the VBA IDE) to explore the differences between the various objects.

Comment: Thank you, indeed. I stilla have to correct the xPath way you gave, which is actually `/sub:QueryResultRecords/sub:OnlyNodeType`

Comment: `/sub:QueryResultRecords/sub:OnlyNodeType` and `//sub:OnlyNodeType` are equivalent, at least for the sample XML you have shown.